# Removing a folder from cloned git Repo is not deleting folders from remote repository

Tags: git

I am a newbie to git. I have read many write-up about cleaning git Repo before asking my question on this forum.The suggested solutions on this site have not worked for me, the deleted directory still exist in remote repository. After a completion of git repo cleanup steps, I still see the deleted folder(download/1508) when I access git repo using the URL (https://hostname/test/FPCNAV_TEST_DATA).

The goal is to remove aged folder from remote git repository and free-up space.

Also, please explain me what "refs/original" is for in command string "git for-each-ref --format='%(refname)' refs/original". Is this suppose to be a pattern  name for a folder in my local .git directory or what? Thanks.

Here are the commands that I run and their condensed output.  Please help.

```
$ /home/john>git clone git@hostname:XYZD/FPCNAV_TEST_DATA
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/john/FPCNAV_TEST_DATA/.git/
...

$ find .git/refs -type f    <<<--- Has nothing to do with Repo cleanup
.git/refs/heads/master
.git/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD

$ git filter-branch --force --index-filter 'git rm --cached 
      --ignore-unmatch download/1508' --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all

Rewrite 04f4ba443b1f939a05592c5af174456b7076fa0b (2/4)
...
Rewrite 33c7db2e753af4ef8ae392274ca9f09af5c928ad (3/4)
..
Rewrite 1019e38ffc7b1739d7f4c4c94cd68884a12c5e54 (4/4)
...
WARNING: Ref 'refs/heads/master' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/master' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/master' is unchanged

$for ref in $(git for-each-ref --format='%(refname)' refs/original); 
         do git update-ref -d $ref; done

$git push origin master --force
Enter passphrase for key '/home/john/.ssh/id_rsa':
Everything up-to-date

$git reflog expire --expire=now --all

$git gc --prune=now

Counting objects: 28, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (22/22), done.
Writing objects: 100% (28/28), done.
Total 28 (delta 1), reused 28 (delta 1)

$git push origin --force --all
Enter passphrase for key '/home/john/.ssh/id_rsa':
Everything up-to-date

$git push origin --force --tags
Enter passphrase for key '/home/john/.ssh/id_rsa':
Everything up-to-date
```

Answer (score 1):

> The goal is to remove aged folder from remote git repository and free-up space.

You have 2 main options

- `git filter-branch`
- `BFG`

---

> #### BFG Repo-Cleaner
>
> an alternative to git-filter-branch.
>
> The BFG is a simpler, faster alternative to git-filter-branch for cleansing **bad data** out of your Git repository history:
>
> - Removing Crazy Big Files
> - Removing Passwords, Credentials & other Private data

#### Examples (from the official site)

> In all these examples bfg is an alias for java -jar bfg.jar.

```
# Delete all files named 'id_rsa' or 'id_dsa' :
bfg --delete-files id_{dsa,rsa}  my-repo.git
```

[image]

---

You have decided to use `git filter-branch`

> Also, please explain me what `refs/original` is for in command string `git for-each-ref --format='%(refname)' refs/original`.
>
> Is this suppose to be a pattern name for a folder in my local .git directory or what?

---

### ***`ref/original`***

Those are backup ref made by the `filter-branch`. They are there is case you decide to quit or if you did something wrong so that the original ref will not be damaged.

If you want to remove them manually use this:

```
# Remove the original refs backed up by git-filter-branch: 
git for-each-ref --format="%(refname)" refs/original/ | xargs -n 1 git update-ref -d
```

Those refs are indeed under your `.git` folder. As mentioned above they are used and managed by the `git filter-branch`

Comment: Hi CodeWizard, I can't use BFG since it has dependency on JVM. Could you answer my below question.

Comment: After a completion of git Repo cleanup steps, I still see the deleted folder(download/1508) when I access the  repository using  URL (https://hostname/test/FPCNAV_TEST_DATA). Is all of my cleanup steps are correct or is there something I am missing?  By the way,             Thank you so much for answering one of my question about refs/original.  Thanks.

Comment: When you clean you do locally. now you have to push the cleaned code:  `git push -f <branch>`

Comment: I did run "git push ..." command but the folder download/1508 is not being removed from remote git repo. Please see below.                                  $git push origin master --force
Enter passphrase for key '/home/john/.ssh/id_rsa':
Everything up-to-date